# Path for picked file is throwing null check error in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, file

I have a profile picture card which I am using in 3 different places. I am passing some parameters to the `ProfilePictureCard` to show camera button.

For an example if the `ProfilePictureCard` is used in a ProfilePage the camera button will be hidden and if the said card is shown in a EditProfilePage the camera button will be visible.

This is the code for `ProfilePictureCard`:

```
class ProfilePictureCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool? isSetProfilePage;
  final bool? isEditable;
  File? imageFile;
  final String? imageUrl;
  ProfilePictureCard({
    Key? key,
    this.isSetProfilePage = false,
    this.isEditable = false,
    this.imageFile,
    this.imageUrl,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfilePictureCardState createState() => _ProfilePictureCardState();
}

class _ProfilePictureCardState extends State<ProfilePictureCard> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('Image Url: ${widget.imageUrl}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 150,
      width: 150,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: _buildProfilePicture(),
              ),
              widget.isEditable == true
                  ? Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,
                      left: 55,
                      right: 55,
                      child: CameraButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _handleChangeProfilePicture();
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  : Container(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildProfilePicture() {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        border: Border.all(
          color: CustomColors.semiSecondary,
          width: 1,
        ),
      ),
      child: _buildImage(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildImage() {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      child: widget.imageFile != null
          ? Image.file(
              widget.imageFile!,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )
          : Image.network(
              widget.imageUrl ?? 'https://picsum.photos/200',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
    );
  }

  void _handleChangeProfilePicture() async {
    final result = await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return CameraDialog();
      },
    );
    print("Result: $result");
    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        widget.imageFile = result;
      });
      print(widget.imageFile);
    }
  }
}
```

_handleChangeProfilePicture takes a picture from either gallery or camera and returns it using `Navigator.of(context).pop(finalImage);`

In my EditProfilePage I have a `Update` Button which for now only prints out the selected images path.

The `EditProfilePage` file looks like this:

```
class _EditProfilePage extends State<EditProfilePage {
    File? imageFile;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
       ...other widgets
       ProfilePictureCard(
          isEditable: true, // because of this line the camera button is visible
          imageFile: imageFile,
          imageUrl: 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300', // previous profile picture, will be replaced with selected image
       )
    }
    
    _handleUpdate(){
       print(imageFile.path);
    }
}
```

Inside the CameraDialog other than the basic UI stuff for returning the selected file I have this:

```
  void _captureImage(context) async {
    final XFile? pickedFile =
        await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      final File file = File(pickedFile.path);
      Navigator.of(context).pop(file);
    }
  }
```

But when I press update I am getting: `Null check operator used on a null value`  from the `print(imageFile.path);`

What is the reason for this issue, and how to solve this?

Comment: You sure that the error is caused by the `print(imageFile.path)`? That error happens when the exclamation mark is used on some `null` value: the code is stating that the object will never be `null`, but at runtime the app finds that it is indeed null, hence the error. I'd look carefully if all the occurences of `!` are actually null-safe.

Comment: My bad I forgot to add the imageFile!.path in the question. And yes i the error specifically shows that imageFile is throwing error. My File object declared in EditprofilePage is not receiving the Filw returned from the camera dialog widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use function to return your image instead of passing object,

```
class ProfilePictureCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool? isSetProfilePage;
  final bool? isEditable;
  final Function(File file) handleUpdate;
  final String? imageUrl;
  ProfilePictureCard({
    Key? key,
    this.isSetProfilePage = false,
    this.isEditable = false,
    this.handleUpdate,
    this.imageUrl,
  })
```

usage

```
if (result != null) {
    widget.handleUpdate(result);
}
```

In editing profile

```
 class _EditProfilePage extends State<EditProfilePage {
    File? imageFile;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
       ...other widgets
       ProfilePictureCard(
          isEditable: true, // because of this line the camera button is visible
          handleUpdate: _handleUpdate,
          imageUrl: 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300', // previous profile picture, will be replaced with selected image
       )
    }
    
    _handleUpdate(File file){
       print(file.path);
       setState(() {
         imageFile = file;
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting the error from `print(imageFile.path);` Rather from inside the `handleUpdate` method

Comment: you mean this _handleUpdate(){
       print(imageFile.path);
    }
method?

Comment: yes. it is supposed to get the selected image from `ProfilePictureCard` and print the path of the file

Comment: yeah you're using different object that's still null. Pay attention to the object you're using State's local object but you've assigned to Widget's object

Comment: Umm I am a bit confused. Can you kindly point out the mistake?

Comment: Sure, just check the original answer updated it for you

Comment: how can I do widget.imageFile.path when the File object is declared inside the EditProfilePage? I am passing the File Object from `EditProfilePage` to `ProfilePictureCard`

Comment: Totally my bad man sincere apologies, updated answer again

Comment: Ah, the old callback function, totally slipped my mind. Your solution worked man, thanks a lot. I will put my working code here as well.

Comment: Thanks man, but again my bad. Have a nice day